# Retrieving data feed from a closed Facebook group

Tags: facebook-graph-api, oauth-2.0

I am trying to retrieve the data feed from a closed facebook group trough server-to-server call using graph api v2.8.

The access token is obtained by configuring my OAuth 2.0 provider with the following parameters:

```
OAuth2ClientOptions credentials = new OAuth2ClientOptions()
    .setClientID(CLIENT_ID)
    .setClientSecret(CLIENT_SECRET)
    .setSite("https://www.facebook.com")
    .setAuthorizationPath("/dialog/oauth")  
    .setTokenPath("https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token");
```

CLIENT_ID and CLIENT_SECRET values are received from facebook after registering a new application there.

The response I get from the facebook server (graph.facebook.com) is:

```
{
   "error": {
      "message": "Unsupported get request. Object with ID '...' does not exist, cannot be loaded due to missing permissions, or does not support this operation. Please read the Graph API documentation at https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api",
      "type": "GraphMethodException",
      "code": 100,
      "fbtrace_id": "D91Fkk/Gmx8"
   }
}
```

The same code can be successfully used to access an OPEN facebook group. In addition, there is no problem to read the data inside the CLOSED group from Graph API Explorer using a user token. Seems to be security problem.

How can I configure the permissions of my facebook application so that I can reach the data also inside a CLOSED group?

Regards,
Mihail

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume that you are not an Admin/Moderator of the group. Afaik you can only read posts of a closed group with a User token of a Moderator.

An App Token cannot work for this, there is no relation to any User. You MUST use a User Token.

Comment: I am an admin of the group. I guess that's why when I use a user token (e.g. from Graph API Explorer) I can get the data successfully.

Comment: did you select YOUR app in the api explorer? and are you sure you asked for the correct permissions?

Comment: When I select my app in the api explorer I am only able to access public group content. I am an admin/moderator of the closed group that I want to read but I have not asked for any particular permissions for the app up to now. On the other hand selecting my user token to get the closed group feed is working fine

Comment: so...with the same api version, and the exact same permissions, you can only access the closed group if you select the api explorer app, but not with your own app, right?

Comment: maybe it´s just not possible anymore. what for do you need to access it anyway, if i may ask?

Comment: "so...with the same api version, and the exact same permissions..." - no, my own app behaves exactly as graph api explorer when selecting app token - only the public groups are "visible". When I use user token even the closed group feed is available (as I am an admin of the closed group). Question is how to enrich the app token with more permissions so that I an access also the closed group.

Comment: so...your problem is that it does not work with an app token, but it does work with a user token? just to get this right before i update my answer.

Comment: see the update in my answer. app tokens don´t work for this, of course. they are closed for specific users (the members), so you need a user token.

Comment: ok. if I request user_managed_groups permission for my facebook app will I still not be able to get the feed? According to the description this permission "Lets your app read the content of groups a person is an admin of" - https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/permissions#reference-user_managed_groups

Comment: you need a user token, that is important. you can´t even request any permission for an app token.

Comment: does that mean that I cannot obtain the token trough oauth service and have to create/refresh it manually?

Comment: user tokens can only be generated manually and they are only valid for 60 days (if you extend them)